# XORing "Hello World!" cuts off string

Tags: c++, c, xor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char greeting[]="\nHello World!\n";
    int a;

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(greeting); i++)
        greeting[i]^=111;

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(greeting); i++)
        greeting[i]^=111;

    printf("%s\n",greeting);    
    scanf("%d",&a);

}
```

Output:

```
Hell
```

Why does it cut everything after spotting a letter corresponding to the XOR key's number (in this case, ASCII 'w')?  In mathematical logic, `N^N=0` and `0^N=N`, doesn't it?

Comment: [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/u6ZNf)

Comment: This is supposed to be simple XOR encryption, right?

Comment: Not a homework,I think it's just a good and concise excercise for perceptiveness. I am the author of this question =)

Comment: Is this a quiz or a real problem you have? I don't think this site is the place for quizzes.

Comment: I agree with you,but I didn't know the answer before asking. It was a real problem that I encountered during developing a larger program.

Comment: Note that you've got a [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) in there, which is a pretty strong code smell.  As it happens, fixing that will fix the truncation bug as well.

Comment: @DanielPryden  +1 for an observation more important than the analysis of the cause of the XOR-induced premature termination.  I am sick & tired of seeing people write for-loops with unnecessary function calls in their termination condition.  I've seen loops that should take microseconds to complete take multiple milliseconds due to things like this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Because `'o'` is ASCII code 111, and XORing 111 with 111 yields 0, `NUL`, and terminates your string.  Once this happens (even in the first loop, since you're evaluating it each time through the loop), `strlen` reports the string is much shorter, and the loops stop.

Saving the string length before going through the XORs will save you from this.

Comment: Note that to fix this, he should save the return value of `strlen` before he mutates the string.

Comment: @NicolBolas He mutates it and then unmutates it and after that the original string is obtained, so proof: http://ideone.com/omgw0

Comment: +1. Note that the xoring affect the first loop too - it doesn't go after the 'o'.

Comment: Incorporated comments.  Thanks!  (I didn't think about the first loop initially.)

Answer (score 10):

This is because when you xor a number with itself, it becomes zero, and when strlen sees zero, it thinks it's the end of the string.

If you store the length in a variable before the first loop and then use that saved length in your second loop instead of strlen, your program will produce the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

`greeting[5]` is 'o' which is 111 in ASCII.
Hence greeting[5] ^ 111 will be zero (which will terminate your string)
The strlen in the second loop will return a different value.

To fix this, use a variable len to store the original strlen.
You will get your string back !!!

**Modified:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char greeting[]="\nHello World!\n";
    int a;
    int len = strlen(greeting);

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        greeting[i]^=111;

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
        greeting[i]^=111;

    printf("%s\n",greeting);    
    scanf("%d",&a);

}
```